# AngularJS $http call response not updating on the view

Tags: angularjs

I am doing a $http call, after the call, I am getting error response which has
to be shown on the view, I could see the error message in console log but its
not showing on the view.
I am assigning error message on the $scope to a variable and interpolating
the same on view

Below is the service part of the $http call

```
userService.getUser = function(searchByNum){
        var q = $q.defer();

        $http({
            method:'GET',
            url :'http://localhost:8083/simpro1/helloRest/user/'+searchByNum
        }).success(function(response){

            userService.user=response;
            q.resolve(response);
        }).error(function(error){

            userService.errors = error;
            q.reject(error);
        })

        return  q.promise;
    }
```

Below is the controller part

```
$scope.getDetails = function(searchByNum){

          userService.getUser(searchByNum)
          .then(function(res){
              console.log(res);
          },function(error){

              **$scope.errMessages = userService.errors.errMessage;**
          })
      }
```

In the above error block assigning the message to variable $scope.errMessages
 but the same is not updated on the view but I could see the error message
 on console.

Could some one help me with this please....

below is the view which {{errMessages}} variable

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">


    <title>Jumbotron Template for Bootstrap</title>


  <body ng-controller="contactHomeCtrl">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <div>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">{{username | capitalizeFirstLetter }}</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" text-align="right"  class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <a class="navbar-brand"  href="#" ng-click="logout()">Logout</a>
        </div>
         <div> </div>


    <!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>U R Fired</h1>
        <p>This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large callout called a jumbotron and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique.</p>
        <p>
        <div has-permission = "['administration', 'ROLE_ADMIN']">
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ui-sref="#" role="button">Learn more &raquo;</a>
        </div>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <!-- Example row of columns -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h5>Enter the Number to Search</h5>
            <div ui-view="contactByNumber"></div>   
            </div>

         <div class="col-md-4">

          **<div>{{errMessages}} </div>**
       </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">

          <div></div>
       </div>


      <hr>

      <footer>

      </footer>
    </div> <!-- /container -->

  </body>
</html>


console.log("error message"+userService.errors.errMessage); results in 
No Customer is found with Id

console.log("error Object"+JSON.stringify(error)); results in complex object      
with all the html messages this is also a failure message
```

Comment: Show us your view, and also check`console.log(userService.errors.errMessage)` and `console.log(error)` in the service $http

Comment: Don't use `.success()` and `.error()` in your service. They're deprecated. Also remember that in the service's `.success()` function the `response` variable holds *data*, not the entire response.

Comment: In what controller the `$scope.getDetails = function(searchByNum){}`  function is defined? is it on `contactHomeCtrl`?

Comment: @Alton Eitan, Thanks for responding, yes its in contactHomeCtrl

Answer (score 0):

You are using `console.log` in your success function, and `$scope.errMessages` in your error function. Either the `console.log` will execute(if the promise resolves successfully) or the `$scope.errMessages` variable will be set(if it rejects).

Remember that the variable will only be set **if** the promise rejects **and** the value of userService.errors is not *undefined*.

That said, why assign the variable to *userService.errors* directly? Just send that data in your reject and assign in the *.then()* error function.

Comment: I am interntionally checking on the error scenario. sent data in reject and directly assigning in thens error function, this problem is occuring with success scenario also

Comment: Then why are you throwing your function `userService.getUser()`'s error response away? I see only one console.log here and if that shows, it means the getUser() function is resolving successfully.

Comment: 20 yes the getUser function is resolving successfully we can see the result in log but not updated on view

Answer (score -1):

Print error using `$timeout` which may start the new digest cycle.

```
 $timeout(function() {
  $scope.errMessages = userService.errors.errMessage;
 }, 300)
```

Put this line in your error block. And don't forget to add $timeout as dependancy

Comment: How will it help? The OP is using angular services, so I couldn't see how this is going to solve the issue